# How do we import Blockly into an Angular 7 application?

Tags: angular, blockly, angular7

I'm trying to use Blockly in an Angular 7 application but I'm unable to inject the Blockly editor.

I have downloaded the files from https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/get-started/web and copied blockly_compressed.js into my src directory (and renamed it blockly.js). I then try to access Blockly from my component and get errors.

What I have tried:

import "../blockly.js"

Does not compile, gives "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Blockly'."

```
import { Blockly } from '../blockly'
```

Compiles, but gives the following error when the app is opened in a browser:

```
ERROR TypeError: _blockly__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.Blockly.inject is not a function
```

Adding a blockly.d.ts file with the following:

```
export namespace Blockly {
    export function inject(div: string, config: any): void;
}
```

Gives the same error as above.

Any suggestions on what else I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to setup with the config mentioned below -

install blockly with npm -

```
npm install git://github.com/google/blockly.git#1.20190419.0
```

included below files in scripts section of angular.json file -

```
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/blockly/blockly_compressed.js",
      "node_modules/blockly/blocks_compressed.js",
      "node_modules/blockly/msg/js/en.js",
      "src/assets/blockly/custom_blocks.js"
    ]
```

added below lines in my component html file -

```
  <div id="blocklyDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
  <xml id="toolbox" style="display: none">
    <category name="Control" colour="120">
      <block type="controls_if"></block>
      <block type="controls_repeat_ext" disabled="true"></block>
    </category>
    <category name="Text" colour="230">
      <block type="text"></block>
      <block type="text_print"></block>
    </category>
    <category name="Custom" colour="360">
      <block type="begin"></block>
      <block type="move"></block>
      <block type="end"></block>
    </category>
  </xml>
```

angular will throw error at this point saying it does not recognise the blockly tags. So need to use NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA in the module or can represent the toolbar XML as a string in the component TS file and use it to inject blockly.

my component TS file -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ProgramService } from '../services/program.service';
import { IProgram } from '../models/program';

declare var Blockly: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-program-create',
  templateUrl: './program-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./program-create.component.scss']
})
export class ProgramCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;
  programName: string;
  program: IProgram;
  workspace: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private programService: ProgramService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.title = 'Create Visual Program';
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.programName = params['programName'];
      this.program = this.programService.getOne(this.programName);
      if (!this.program) {
        this.program = {
          name: this.programName,
          xmlData: null
        };
      }
      console.log(
        'creating/editing the program - ',
        JSON.stringify(this.program)
      );
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {
      toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox'),
      scrollbars: false
    });

    if (this.program.xmlData) {
      this.workspace.clear();
      Blockly.Xml.domToWorkspace(
        Blockly.Xml.textToDom(this.program.xmlData),
        this.workspace
      );
    }
  }

  saveProgram(): void {
    this.program.xmlData = Blockly.Xml.domToText(
      Blockly.Xml.workspaceToDom(this.workspace)
    );
    console.log('saving the program - ', JSON.stringify(this.program));
    this.programService.upsertOne(this.program);
    this.router.navigate(['listProgram']);
  }
}
```

I have written an article explaining this in details here - [Integrate Google Blockly with Angular](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/integrate-google-blockly-with-angular/)

Answer (score 3):

My answer does not put the XML into the template itself, but rather in a variable which enable the integration without the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA import in the module.

**Step 1:** Download the files from Blockly website, and look for:

- blockly_compressed.js
- blocks_compressed.js
- en.js
  (Or any language that you want your blockly to be in)

  Copy and paste them into src/assets/blockly.

**Step 2:** In your angular.json file, add the following ( in projects.architect.build.options ):

```
"scripts": [
          "src/assets/blockly/blockly_compressed.js",
          "src/assets/blockly/blocks_compressed.js",
          "src/assets/blockly/en.js"
]
```

**Step 3:**
In your component.ts :

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var Blockly: any

@Component({
  template: `<div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 480px; width: 600px;"></div>`,
  selector: 'app-blockly',
  styleUrls: ['./blockly.component.scss']
})

export class BlocklyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const toolbox = `
      <xml>
        <block type="controls_if"></block>
        <block type="controls_whileUntil"></block>
      </xml>`;
    Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', { toolbox });
  }
}
```

And that's it !

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using @angular/cli.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwx28d?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Step 1:  Install blockly

```
npm install blockly
```

Step 2:  Add scripts to `angular.json` under the architect node:

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/blockly/blockly_compressed.js",
   "node_modules/blockly/blocks_compressed.js",
   "node_modules/blockly/msg/js/en.js"
]
```

Step 3:  Add `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` to your AppModule (this is so that you can define custom tags in your components)

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  exports: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Step 4: Create a Component, declare Blockly as `any`, and implement `AfterViewInit` so that you can access the blockly-related elements in the DOM:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare var Blockly: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 480px; width: 600px;"></div>
    <xml id="toolbox" #toolbox style="display: none">
            <block type="controls_if"></block>
            <block type="logic_compare"></block>
            <block type="controls_repeat_ext"></block>
            <block type="math_number"></block>
            <block type="math_arithmetic"></block>
            <block type="text"></block>
            <block type="text_print"></block>
    </xml>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  workspace: any;
  @ViewChild('toolbox') toolbox: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv',
    {toolbox: this.toolbox.nativeElement });
  }
}
```

NOTE: The Blockly package in NPM is at v1.0, while the latest version is v1.2. To use the latest, just download the library, put it in a known directory, and fix your script references (Step 2).

Comment: I had to import NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA from @angular/core to get rid of a compile error when modifying app.module.ts.

Comment: Tried all of the steps and it still doesn't work: getting `ReferenceError: Blockly is not defined` in ngAfterViewInit().

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. For some reason the demo doesn't work on my PC at all (I tried three different browsers). I'll try again on another machine in case there is something screwed up on my machine.

Comment: Yeah, I think Stackblitz behaves differently when dealing with globals. If you try locally should work

Comment: The demo is not working 
Cannot read property 'inject' of undefined.
doesn't look like any thing Machine Specific.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngx-blockly` instead of `blockly` , ngx-blockly is angular port of blockly.

follow the steps explained in npm page

```
npm install ngx-blockly --save
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-blockly

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to `angular.json` firstly.
So angular CLI can build it.

```
        "scripts": [
          "../blockly.js"
        ]
```